What is the pinout for the 9-pin connector on a 97Wh Dell laptop battery?
enter image description here1


I'm working with a 97Wh battery from a Dell laptop, and I'm trying to understand the pinout of its 9-pin connector for troubleshooting and possible repairs. I know the pins are used for power, communication, and monitoring the battery's status, but I need more specific details on the exact pin configuration.
Could someone provide the pinout for the 9-pin connector on this type of Dell laptop battery, including which pins correspond to positive (VBAT), ground (GND), temperature sensor, SMBus communication, and other functions?
For reference, I'm working with a Dell laptop model [latitude 6440] and the battery part number is [type:71R31
https://we.tl/t-cxjMrLM5iA
https://we.tl/t-k3sErU88uE
https://we.tl/t-6lPDv7OmJm
https://we.tl/t-VYf27OD4bX

So trace the pins.

what is the top picture supposed to show?

It is with burnt resistance that cannot be verified
